# Docker build Share data with host

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nexe

I hava a custom Dockerfile that setup and builds a project of mine.
But now I haven't beeing able to place that into a folder of the host. Here the script and docker file...

Command

```
sudo docker build --output type=local,dest=./build/server/server -f ./build/scripts/Dockerfile.server ./server
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14 AS build-stage

WORKDIR /usr/src/project
RUN npm i nexe@3.3.7 -g
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
RUN nexe server.js -t linux-x64-12.14.1

FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/project/server /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker buildkit needs to be enabled before running the build command:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

You are setting up the context wrong. The command should be:

```
sudo docker build --output type=local,dest=./build/server/server -f ./build/scripts/Dockerfile.server .
```

The dot at the end sets the build context to current directory structure.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve.The folder structure is the following: build, client and server; the server source code is in the server folder, thats why ./server

Comment: Just curious, since the WORKDIR is set to /usr/src/project, if you can try changing the COPY --from=build-stage command to replace '/usr/src/project/server' with '/usr/src/project' and see if it makes any difference. Interesting issue though

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Comment: Ok one more thing to try: please enable buildkit before running the build command. Run: export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 and then run the docker build command.

Comment: I think thats the problem, but even with DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 it is not running in that mode and i have docker 19.03

Comment: I Forgot to restart deamon, thank and sorry for your time

Comment: no problems, just wanted to understand the root cause. Good luck going forward.